# DataType to store and use generic types with specific restrictions?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I feel this should be easy but my brain is having issues with it this morning.

I have a custom `UserControl` bound to a custom `ItemsSource`. I would like to set it up to draw each item using a matching `Control` based on how the user defined to draw the items.

For example, I want to be able to do this from the class that uses the control

```
var data = new List<object>();
data.Add(new MyClassA());
data.Add(new MyClassB());
data.Add(new MyClassB());

myCustomControl.ItemsSource = myObjectArray;

myCustomControl.ResourceLibrary = {
    { MyClassA, ctlClassA },
    { MyClassB, ctlClassB }
}
```

And in my custom control, something along these lines

```
foreach(var item in ItemsSource)
{
    var key = item.GetType();

    if (ResourceLibrary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var ctlType = ResourceLibrary[key];
        if (ctlType != null)
        {
            var ctl = new ctlType();
            // Do something with control
        }
    }
}
```

What kind of data type can I use for `ResourceLibrary` that would allow me to do this? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this task?

I would also like to be able to restrict the types passed in to only allowing types `where T : Control, new()`

I'm using WinForms, C#, and .Net 3.5

Comment: One of your problems will be  `var ctl = new ctlType();`, C# doesn't do virtual constructors.

Comment: With MVVM and Caliburn, replace/wrap this as `MyClassAViewModel` and `MyClassAView` and the whole thing becomes automagic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I wish I could use WPF for this, but it's WinForms and .Net 3.5

Comment: Heh.. you're implementing an `ItemsControl` in winforms? that's cool.. is the code proprietary? otherwise it'd be awesome if you can share it.

Comment: @HighCore I'm not trying anything quite so advanced... I just want a bindable TabControl. It seems like it's a bit too much to ask WinForms for... =/

Comment: @Rachel you might want to introduce the concept of a `Binder<TModel,TView>` to all this which can perform the needed initialization of the View from the Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the most basic level, I think something like this might help:

```
public class DataTemplateManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> dataTemplates = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    public void Add<TModel, TView>() where TView : Control, new()
    {
        dataTemplates.Add(typeof (TModel), typeof (TView));
    }

    public void Add(Type modelType, Type viewType)
    {
        if (!typeof (Control).IsAssignableFrom(viewType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("viewType must derive from System.Windows.Forms.Control");

        dataTemplates.Add(modelType, viewType);
    }

    public Control Resolve(object model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            return null;

        var type = model.GetType();

        if (!dataTemplates.ContainsKey(type))
            return null;

        var viewType = dataTemplates[type];

        var control = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);

        return control as Control;
    }
}
```

then simply have a property of this type into your control:

```
public class MyControl: Control
{
    public DataTemplateManager DataTemplateManager {get; private set;}

    public MyControl()
    {
        this.DataTemplateManager = new DataTemplateManager();
    }
}
```

Which then you could use like this:

```
myControl1.DataTemplateManager.Add<MyModel1, MyView1>();
myControl1.DataTemplateManager.Add<MyModel2, MyView2>();
myControl1.DataTemplateManager.Add<MyModel3, MyView3>();
```

and use the `Resolve()` method like so:

```
foreach(var item in ItemsSource)
{
    var ctl = this.DataTemplateManager.Resolve(item);

    //.. do something with ctl     
}
```

Also, I can think of very useful features to add to this, such as the concept of `IBinder<TModel,TView>` which would take care of the `do something with ctl..` part:

```
public interface IBinder<TModel,TView>
{
     void Bind(TModel model, TView view);
}

public class MyBinder: IBinder<MyModel1,MyView1>
{
    public void Bind(MyModel1 model, MyView1 view)
    {
         view.SomeProperty = model.SomeOtherProperty;
         //.. And so on.
    }
}
```

Then:

```
myControl.DataTemplateManager.AddBinder<TModel1,TView1,MyBinder>();
```

and use it in the `Resolve()` method.

Notice that this doesn't handle inheritance, or generics. Thinks get a little bit more complex if you need to support those scenarios, but it's still doable.

BTW, I tried to make this as abstract as possible. Otherwise people might think I'm writing winforms code...

Comment: Wow nice job with this one! I'm going to have to give you some extra bounty rep when I can. :)